# Run Swagger docker container as extension of server

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, swagger-ui, swagger-codegen

I have a docker compose file serving the `nginx:alpine` image for an API I'm developing. I also have a container for swagger ui and another for swagger editor. The nginx container is setup to support SSL via container port 443 (mapped via the host port 9443 as I also use Laravel Valet in secure mode for other small projects).

My question is, how can I get swagger containers to be routed, such that my team can visit `https://domain.dev/swagger-ui` and `https://domain.dev/swagger-editor` in my browser in my dev environment rather than `https://localhost:8081` and `https://localhost:8082` respectively?

Here's my docker-compose YAML file

```yaml
version: "3.3"

services:

  nginx:
    container_name: "cygnus-nginx"
    image: nginx:alpine
    restart: "always"
    command: /bin/sh -c "nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
    ports:
      - "9800:80"
      - "9443:443"
    volumes:
      - "./docker/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d:delegated"
      - "./docker/nginx/ssl/:/etc/nginx/ssl:delegated"
      - ".:/var/www/html:delegated"

  swagger-editor:
    container_name: "cygnus-swagger-editor"
    image: swaggerapi/swagger-editor
    restart: "always"
    ports:
      - "8081:8080"

  swagger-ui:
    container_name: "cygnus-swagger-ui"
    image: swaggerapi/swagger-ui
    restart: "always"
    ports:
      - "8082:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./swagger/swagger.json:/swagger.json
    environment:
      SWAGGER_JSON: /swagger.json
```

and my `/etc/hosts` file:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
127.0.0.1       mydomain.dev
```

Any pointers on this? Thanks in advance!